# buttons that link to other pages vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm looking to link several buttons to several other forms in vb.net i have not used this program very much and i got rushed into it i heard the f2.show() will work but not for this apparently my other form is called setform.vb i connect to that i should be able to do everything else i need to remember i need this brought up in another window to

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    setform.show()
End Sub
```

Comment: What is exactly your problem? Because you are already linking to another form.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  In what way does `setform.show()` not work?

Comment: @Liath: Every indication suggests that this is a WinForms application, not WebForms.

Comment: it is winforms i need to just to bring up another window and it does not want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open other form you have 2 options, opening the default form or an instance of the form - preferred.

If your form name is setform.

```
'default way
setform.Show()

'instance version
Dim sf As New setform
sf.Show()
```

Comment: when i highlight it, it said 'setform' was not declared.it may be inaccessible due to its protection level. there is no protection

Comment: then that is not the name of your form. We don't know the names of your forms, only you do. So replace that with your form name.